# :last-child doesn't work with additional content at the end

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following scenario:

```
<div> 
 <p>A</p>
 <p>A</p>
 <p>Target me</p>
 <form></form>
</div>
```

And I want to target the last `<p>` tag. Normally, this would work:

```
div p:last-child {

}
```

But it only works if I remove the `<form>` tag. My question: Is it possible to target the final P tag regardless if there is other content at the end?

Comment: Yes - `div p:last-of-type{}`

Comment: That works. Please post answer.